# Strange error with titleps \setfoot

Tags: graphics, titleps

I'm trying to compile this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
    \setfoot{}{}{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{logo}}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

Test.

\end{document}
```

And it fails:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titleps.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/ttlps.def))

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \pagestyle{mystyle}

?
```

But if I move the `\includegraphics` to the second argument of `\setfoot`, then it works:

```
\setfoot{}{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{logo}}{}
```

I read the `titleps` docs but I didn't find anything that explains this, but I may be missing something obvious here. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, the optional argument to `\includegraphics` confuses the working of `\pagestyle`. Add braces:

```
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \setfoot{}{}{{\includegraphics[width=30mm]{logo}}}%
}
```

Comment: For some reasons, I knew @egreg would provide the workaround; he was the one who thought me LaTeX, after all :-)